# How to use the xarray.Dataset.sel function?

Tags: python, dataset, python-xarray

In Python, I have two xarray.Dataset objects which represent remote sensing images for the same grid over one year, but cover areas of different sizes:

ds1:

```
xarray.Dataset 
Dimensions:time: 365 lat: 252 lon: 802  
Coordinates:  
*time(time) datetime64[ns] 2018-01-01 ... 2018-12-31  
latitude (lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(252, 802), meta=np.ndarray>  
longitude (lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(252, 802), meta=np.ndarray>  
Data variables: soil_moisture (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 252, 802), meta=np.ndarray>
```

ds2:

```
xarray.Dataset  
Dimensions: time: 364 lat: 406 lon: 964  
Coordinates:    
*time (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-01-01 ... 2018-12-31  
longitude (lat, lon) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(406, 964), meta=np.ndarray>  
latitude (lat, lon) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(406, 964), meta=np.ndarray>  
Data variables:  
soil_moisture (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 406, 964), meta=np.ndarray>
```

How can I get the subset of ds2 according to the coordinates of ds1?
`ds1 = ds1.sel(time = ds2.time)`,
Can keep the time dimension align.

The following code has been used:
`ds2_subset = ds2.sel(latitude=ds1.latitude, longitude=ds1.longitude, method='nearest')`
and got KeyError: "no index found for coordinate 'latitude'"

I want to get a subset of ds2 with the same coordinates as ds1 (time 364, lat: 252, lon: 802), Maybe it needs a tolerance parameter since the latitude and longitude have different date types: float32 and float 64.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you have dimensions `lon` and `lat`, but you don't have coordinates for `lon` and `lat`. You only have the coordinates latitude and longitude. Why is for example `latitude` a function of `lat` *and* `lon`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`.interp_like()`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.interp_like.html). So, using it like this:

```
ds2_subset = ds2.interp_like(ds1)
```

will give you the interpolated (meaning exactly the same coordinates) subset of `ds2`, based on the coordinates of `ds1`.

Comment: sorry, it is not work for me.